# I2C only works when probed or loaded with 1Mohm

Tags: i2c, oscilloscope, msp430

I am trying to troubleshoot communications between an msp430fr5847 (master) and a slave sensor with unknown I2C chip (part of an industrial sensor)

I am having issues with a new batch of sensors where my data is being returned with all zeros, however when trying to troubleshoot with my Saleae logic pro (2Mohm, 10pf), or my oscilloscope (10Mohm, 50pf) the system works perfectly when probing the SDA pin.

Troubleshooting further the circuit works correctly if I add a 1Mohm resistor between SDA and ground, but does not work if only adding a 10pf or 100pf capacitor.

I am using 4.7k pull up resistors to my 3.3v rail.

What could be causing this issue, and what can be done to troubleshoot without unintentionally fixing the problem.

---

EDIT: 19/07/2017
Here is a quick scope trace of my signals.

Something else I forgot to mention is that only probing SDA causes the board to work, probing SCL or my interrupt line does not get it to work properly.

[image: Scope trace of SDA and SCL]

---

EDIT: 21/07/2017

The plot thickens, it appears that connecting a different oscilloscope does not get the circuit to work correctly, and it can be seen that the only difference is that an ACK is not being transmitted.

[image: New scope picture]

In the above picture, the blue and green traces are the SCL and SDA when the circuit is not operating correctly. The yellow and pink traces are from when I also connect my Saleae logic to the SDA Pin and ground but without plugging in USB (trying to avoid ground loops).

To add a bit more background on the sensor it is an industrial pressure sensor we buy in from the manufacturer. We have previously designed and tested these PCBs with our first batch of sensors. We have recently received a new batch and are now encountering these issues. I have done a bit of investigation and I strongly suspect (after googling unique looking sentences from the datasheet) that internally the sensor uses a ZSC31014 or similar, PDF datasheet [HERE](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/464/IDT_ZSC31014_DST_20160120-965033.pdf)

---

EDIT: 26/07/2017

So hopefully the last installment in solving this issue, as per SamGibson's detailed answer I have implemented the fix of setting the high bit of the address to mask the glitching at the end of the start bit.

This has worked mostly with data coming through as expected, however now it appears that in in the first read command after a write (if that is the correct term for a group of i2c bits), the slave attempts to ACK one bit early (in the position of the write bit). I can tell that it is the slave pulling the line down through adding a small (47 ohm) resistor in series with the SDA Line.

I would usually start this as a new question but when I attach the same scope that had no effect in the above troubleshooting, this issue seems to go away, this really does seem to be a borderline issue as even if I attach the scope probe, without connecting it to the scope the issue is solved so I am assuming it is a capacitance issue.

Plot of issue with no scope attached

[image: Plot with no scope]

Plot of issue with scope probe attached, but not attached to scope, noting the slightly higher voltage when the slave pulls down the write bit instead of the ACK bit.

[image: With scope attached]

Comment: Do you have any scope traces

Comment: I will try to get one exported to include tomorrow, but at a glance everything looked more or less what I would expect.

Comment: Any cable length to speak of?  Can't understand why your 1Meg addition helps, unless something is not following the standard.  In any case, easiest thing to try first is reducing the size of the pull ups.

Comment: Have you inadvertently inverted your clock signal?

Comment: If there are available, you could perhaps use active FET probes that have even less capacitance than the 10pF that you say you have tried.

Comment: Test different clock speeds.

Comment: Confirm that the I2C bus has, and is using, a common ground wire (MSP to the I2C sensor).  3 wires required: SDA, SCL, and GND, with SDA & SCL pulled up to Vcc (possible 4th wire) through pull-up resistors.

Comment: My signal travels about 20mm across my pcb to where the two pullup resistors are and then goes through a mta100 connector and about 50 mm of multicore cable to the sensor. The cable contains 5 wires gnd,3.3v,SDA,SCL, and an interrupt line.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen - You beat be to it. I was just going to ask if the GND between the sensor and MCU sections were properly tied together. This issue reads an awful lot like a missing or bad common GND.

Comment: I have added a scope trace to the question.

Comment: @Hugoagogo - Yikes! Both SDA & SCL abnormal, in different ways. I assume *that* trace is with the new *failing* sensors? If so, can you supply a trace with the old *working* sensors? Perhaps the difference may not be so big i.e. you had a problem before, but it was *just* working. More background info might reveal useful data e.g. How do you know these are "new" I2C chips, considering the chip is "unknown"? I'm guessing some reverse-engineering was done to allow the MSP430 (which you control?) to be used with a sensor (that you don't control?). How different is that from the "original" config?

Comment: P.S. I can't measure the voltages accurately from that scope image, but the p-p voltage on both I2C signals looks > 3.3V. How did you decide that it was a 3.3V I2C sensor? What is the full list of devices, pull-up resistors etc. on that I2C bus?

Comment: What about it is so irregular, the salaee logic is able to correctly decode the signal. I believe the spikes on the SDA signal (yellow) are measurment error and not real (they dont show up with the logic analyser). The sensor is rated for a supply voltage from 2.7v to 13v. We are currently running at about 3.6 supply from two AA sized lithium thionel batteries. I know how to communicate with it as we were supplied information from the manufacturer on what bytes and commands to send.

Comment: @Hugoagogo - Thanks. Unfortunately we're not communicating well and that doesn't answer all my questions. I've done lots of reverse-engineering over the years, but it needs *much* more detail to properly understand everything. You might be seeing a classic trap of LAs, which is why a scope is important (to view the analog signal). An LA can show a "good" decode, on a signal that is not acceptable to the "real device" e.g. due to different logic thresholds & sample rates. I respectfully disagree that the SDA spikes look like measurement error, but would need higher res image. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Well, I agree with SamGibson. I wouldn't be so quick in saying that the spikes are measurement errors. I think you should try to research it a bit further and try to eliminate them, if they come from your measurement setup or find the reason why they are there. After all, they seem to be aligned with falling edges of SCL. I would also try to hook up the sensor directly on the PCB. That could help you rule out that the problems are caused by the cable or the distance of the sensor from the main board.

Comment: I will try and get some better plots tomorrow when I get back to the office. I can't really change the sensor connection as it is a thick metal can potted with epoxy, and the single 5 core cable coming out. Do you have any recommendations on stocking the spikes. I was thinking increasing the pull up resistance or bits capacitance may help.

Comment: @SamGibson I have added some more plots and information on the sensor.

Comment: @Hugoagogo - Re "EDIT: 26/07/2017" Sorry, I don't understand :-( The main text seems to say that the new problem is *solved* when a scope probe is attached (which makes sense, if we suspect a glitch is the cause). But the text just above each analyser trace seems to say the problem *occurs* when the scope probe is attached, and so contradicts the main text. The bandwidth of the analog channel of the Saleae analysers is very limited (~1MHz?) so I don't trust these images to show enough detail to capture a fast glitch. I can't see a difference on the analog traces, but there must be one. :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I *think* I've found the answer. It turns out this is a known problem, but I only found that after I'd decided where the problem was, and searched for that!

Here is the process I went through, so you can follow it (and, if necessary, you can then adapt your investigation if you see results which differ from my assumptions). The bottom line is that there appears to be an incompatibility between (at least some) MSP430 I²C behaviour, and the required I²C behaviour by the device you suspect to be the I²C Slave, the [IDT ZSC31014](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/464/IDT_ZSC31014_DST_20160120-965033.pdf). Having the datasheet for that device is critical to understanding this, so thanks for finding it.

The good news is that there are (at least) 2 workarounds for this problem, which I'll explain at the end.

> The plot thickens, it appears that connecting a different oscilloscope does not get the circuit to work correctly, and it can be seen that the only difference is that an ACK is not being transmitted.

The new traces are helpful, thanks, although I interpret them a bit differently.

(The SCL signal undershoot, which concerned me on the initial trace, is still there on the latest trace. It's interesting that the undershoot on SCL seems greater than the undershoot on SDA, especially considering the different vertical scales between SCL and SDA signals on the latest trace. I would still suggest to investigate that SCL undershoot eventually, but I don't believe it is related to the main problem.)

There are those two "glitches" on SDA:

- A glitch just before or just after the ACK pulse is not uncommon, when an I²C Master releases control of SDA to allow a Slave to perform the ACK and then the Master might re-drive SDA again. Therefore I'm ignoring that one.
- It is the *early* SDA glitch, before the first SCL pulse, which is more unusual. From the amplitude of that early SDA glitch (see later) and the fact it occurs only before that first SCL pulse (labelled 0), but does not occur before later SCL pulses where we would be able to see a glitch on SDA (like SCL pulses labelled 4, 5, 6 or 7), we know it is not a measurement artefact, nor coupling from SCL (for example).

(For later reference, the early SDA glitch looks like *at least* 2V in the latest trace, so with Vdd at 3.6V from earlier comments, that makes the SDA glitch amplitude at least (2/3.6) = 0.55 x Vdd. Compare that with the relevant I2C logic level thresholds discussed later.)

Ignoring the ACK difference, I believe I see another difference between the two sets of traces in that second screenshot. The amplitude of that *early* SDA glitch seems slightly different, comparing the top SDA trace labelled `C1` (yellow-ish?) and the 2nd SDA trace labelled `M3` (blue). I now believe that differences in the amplitude of that early SDA glitch, is what can cause your issue to appear or disappear, as I explain below.

Even more resolution specifically on the glitch would help (that is one of the problem in trying to work on problems "remotely" - I can't operate the 'scope myself!). I'll assume that when you zoom in, it looks like the start of a normal I²C logic "1" (i.e. an RC curve on the rising edge, especially if you temporarily make the pull-ups weaker e.g. 10k) except it doesn't reach the full positive voltage before it is driven to a logic "0" again. That is what is shown on another webpage linked later. If you see different shape to your glitch, then my later analysis might not apply.

The I²C Master is in control of the bus at the point of that glitch, between the I²C Start and the first SCL clock pulse (which you've labelled "0" although it's the MSbit). That made me suspicious of the MSP430 behaviour, although with SCL low at that point, an SDA glitch *shouldn't* affect I²C-compliant devices, as they will be waiting for SCL to go high before they next read the state of SDA.

So, is that I²C Slave *really* I²C-compliant? It turns out, the ZSC31014 is "*fussy*" and less tolerant than some other I²C devices, at exactly the time when I believe the MSP430 is producing that glitch!

The [ZSC31014 datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/464/IDT_ZSC31014_DST_20160120-965033.pdf) lists 3 areas where they admit the device's I²C behaviour is "different". You might also be affected by the first two in this list at other times (that isn't part of this analysis), but it is the third point which I've marked below in red, which is related to that early SDA glitch:

---

[image: extract from ZSC31014 datasheet]

---

The amplitude of that early SDA glitch is *critical*. If that glitch does not rise enough to be recognised by the ZSC31014 as a logic "1" before it falls again, then you are OK - the device has to see a *falling* edge on SDA to break that "rule" and it can only be a *falling* edge if it has already been recognised as a logic "1".

Anything which affects the amplitude of that SDA glitch, like the additional load of a 'scope or logic analyser on the SDA signal, might be enough to stop the glitch being recognised by the ZSC31014 as reaching a logic "1" and therefore no "falling SDA edge", that third point in the list, can occur (on a good day, depending on voltages, temperatures etc.). However, as you have found, the variation between different oscilloscopes is enough to mean that *some* of them add enough load to stop the problem, and others don't. This setup must be very marginal!

This confirms my worry that your earlier "working" batches of sensors, might be "only just" working, since the MSP430 MCUs on those "working" setups will likely also be producing SDA glitches. My theory about a *possible* difference between batches of sensors, which could explain the different behaviour you have reported ("working" batch vs. "non-working" batch) is explained next.

Interestingly, the ZSC31014 is different from standard I²C in another area which is not mentioned on that list from the manufacturer, and this could explain why you seem to see a difference between batches of sensors.

Standard I²C logic thresholds are (simplified) - below 0.3 x Vdd for logic "0", and above 0.7 x Vdd for logic "1" as shown in the [I²C specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf):

---

[image: logic level thresholds from I2C specification]

---

However the ZSC31014 has *different* thresholds, 0.2 x Vdd and 0.8 x Vdd, meaning that its "undefined region" between those thresholds is *larger* than typical I²C devices:

---

[image: logic level thresholds from ZSC31014 datasheet]

---

That larger "undefined region" *increases* the chance of the glitch entering the undefined voltage level area, where it *might* be recognised as a logic "1" (remember, anything above 0.2 x Vdd *could* be recognised by the ZSC31014 as a logic "1", since in the undefined region, *anything* is allowed - it is only above 0.8 x Vdd when it *must* be recognised as a logic "1"). And, as explained before, *if* the glitch is recognised by the ZSC31014 as having reached a logic "1", then when it falls again to a logic "0", you have broken that "rule" marked in red for the I²C behaviour required by the ZSC31014.

Since the recognition of logic levels in that "undefined" voltage region is not specified, the sensor manufacturer is not breaking the specification if they make one batch that recognises logic "1" only when it reaches 0.7 x Vdd, but make another batch which recognises a logic "1" as low as 0.4 x Vdd, for example. That hypothetical second batch would be more likely to see the SDA glitch as a falling SDA edge, in violation of that third point in their list, yet not be breaking their specification.

(Many of the problems I've worked on, over the years, have been like this: There are two devices, neither of which is individually breaking a specification which has loopholes - but one is fussy and *less* tolerant, on a point where the other one needs connected devices to be *more* tolerant because of *its* obscure behaviour! Each of those two devices is fine interfacing with the majority of other devices, but are unreliable (or completely fail) when connected to each other.)

So what can you do? I thought of two options:

- Don't use an MSP430 - use another MCU which doesn't create that early SDA glitch. However I expect you have invested lots of time in the software and would not want to port the code to another MCU, if that could be avoided.
- "Bit-bang" the I²C protocol on the MSP430, instead of using its built-in I²C hardware module. That way, you are in total control of the I²C signals and can prevent that glitch from occurring. However, it would obviously be some work to create your own I²C routines, debug them, and the resulting code may be larger than when using the MSP430 I²C hardware module, which itself could be a problem if you are short of Flash space.

Then I went searching for MSP430 I²C issues, and I found that this combination of MSP430 + ZSC31014 is a known problem, due to that early SDA glitch from the MSP430! See this thread on the TI E2E MSP430 forum:

[TI E2E forum: MSP430 I2C glitch pulses causing trouble for I2C peripheral chip](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/346885)

The workaround mentioned there, is to change the ZSC31014 I²C address so that SDA is high at the time when the positive glitch *could* occur, and since SDA is made high then anyway, there is no *actual* glitch on SDA:

> Our workaround is to configure the ZSC chip to have an address with its bit 6 set (e.g. we’re now using 0x42) - this turns the glitch pulse into a nice clean "high" bit for the address bit 6 duration, which gets rid of the problematic falling edge.

The same workaround is effectively the reverse of the suggestion in the ZSC31014 datasheet, in the red box which I marked. They say an SDA glitch must be prevented if the first bit (which is the MSbit) of the ZSC31014 I²C address is 0 - so don't make the MSbit of the I²C address a "0", make it a "1" instead i.e. set bit 6 in the 7-bit I²C address!

Since that TI E2E forum thread and the ZSC31014 datasheet are both focussing on the I²C address, then perhaps either the SDA glitch doesn't occur, or is not a problem if it does occur, during the sending of other data on the bus. You will need to investigate that.

Therefore, ignoring the first workaround of using a different MCU, the two (more practical) workarounds are either:

- Bit-bang the MSP430 I²C bus by writing your own code, so that you don't create that glitch on SDA, or
- Change the ZSC31014 I²C address so that bit 6 of its 7-bit address is set, meaning that SDA is already high when the glitch would otherwise occur, so no *actual* glitch occurs on SDA when the ZSC31014 is addressed (assuming that an SDA glitch either doesn't occur after other I²C Start events during data transfer, or if one does occur, that the ZSC31014 doesn't get "upset").

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is an awesome and very helpful answer, before I mark as accepted is there any way I can give you some more rep for sticking with it through the troubleshooting. I will also update my question with my workaround when I get it going.

Comment: @Hugo - That's a very kind thought :-) I believe it can be done by offering a [bounty](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) where the bounty reason would be "[Reward Existing Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/)". I'm not an expert in the process, so I can't say much more than that. Of course I'd be happy to have extra rep (it has taken a few hours to do the analysis and write-up ;-) ) but if you don't want to use a bounty, or can't figure out the process, then no worries, it's all positive karma anyway :-) Hope my answer works!

Comment: @Hugo - I don't know if you get notified of updates to answers, but just FYI, I've added a paragraph about SCL and its undershoot (still a puzzle, but I doubt it's related to the main problem) and I've guesstimated the amplitude of the "early SDA glitch" in the latest scope trace as being at least 0.55 x Vdd, which is well into the "undefined" voltage region, where different sensors (or different *batches* of sensors ;-) ) could treat that as a logic "1" or not, without breaking their specification. I'll be offline for a while soon, so again, good luck!

Comment: Thankyou again for the assistance I will have a go with the bounty on Monday when I am in. (For the record I don't get notified of updates to answers)

Comment: would I be able to get you to weigh in on one last update to the question.

Comment: @Hugoagogo - I'm glad I could help with the original issue, and I'm sorry that you are having more problems. I've replied to your new info under where you put it (although I can't add any analysis, as the info *seems* contradictory). However we need to learn whether this "new" problem is *totally* new, or is it related to the one in this question. If they are different, they may need different solutions, and the cause of the new problem is still unknown :-( I've been thinking about ways to try to improve I2C signal integrity, but they would add h/w complexity and may not fix the "new" problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will mark this as accepted and may ask a new question in the future.

Comment: @Hugoagogo - OK and sincere thanks for adding the bounty, even after this new problem. FWIW I suggest to try to characterise the new problem using a real scope (not the Saleae analog channel). Even if attaching the scope stops the misbehaviour, it may still capture enough detail to better *understand* the problem (as happened on this question, the SDA glitch was still visible). If the slave drives SDA to ACK "one bit too early", it *might* mean the slave thinks it has seen an extra SCL pulse. That *sounds* different to the original problem here, but IMHO it needs new scope traces. Good luck!